# Equations with integrals

Tags: calculus

In a math-textbook I have, they have solved the equation $$ -c_{2}\int_{0}^{S}f(x)dx+c_{1}\int_{S}^{\infty}f(x)dx=0$$ as $$\int_{S}^{\infty}f(x)dx=\frac{c_{2}}{c_{1}+c_{2}}$$. Anyone who know how they arrived at this answer?

Comment: Have you that $\int_0^{+\infty}f(x)dx=1$ as hypothesis ? If yes, use $\int_0^s=\int_0^{+\infty}-\int_s^{+\infty}$.

Comment: Yes, that was the hypothesis. Thank you very much Kelenner, you are golden!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Kelenner's comment. If you have $\int_0^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 1$ then $$\int_0^s f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_s^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x= \int_0^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 1$$

And so $$\int_s^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x =1 - \int_0^s f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$$ and therefore $$c_1\int_s^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = c_2\left(1 - \int_s^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x\right)$$

so rearranging gives $$\int_s^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{c_2}{c_1 + c_2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to mention that
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx=1$$
So the expresion can be written
$$\int_{0}^{S}f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx-\int_{S}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$
$$-c_{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx+c_{1}\int_{S}^{\infty}f(x)dx=0$$
$$-c_{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx+c_{2}\int_{S}^{\infty}f(x)dx+c_{1}\int_{S}^{\infty}f(x)dx=0$$

$$(c_{1}+c_{2})\int_{S}^{\infty}f(x)dx=c_{2}$$
$$